# get function from returning of bind failed

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to get a std::function from result of a std::bind. but I get an error when I am trying to compile the code below, where the data_struct_call_ptr and tracking_call_ptr point to two resource pools which overload their () operators so that they are callable objects.
But they cannot be copied, so I use std::ref here to wrap them.

I should be able to transport the ve_ptr to a lambda which executes asynchronously. However, I get compiling error at the beginning.

the code and compiling error are below. any help will be appreciated.

```
Error VSEService::TaskNew(const NewTaskRequest* req, NewTaskResponse* resp) {
    shared_ptr<::Config> conf(Config::CreateInstance(-1, -1));
    shared_ptr<FrameCallType> data_struct_call_ptr = make_shared<FrameCallType>();
    shared_ptr<TrackCallType> tracking_call_ptr = make_shared<TrackCallType>();

    std::function<void(ObjPtrWithFramePtr)> dc = ref(*data_struct_call_ptr);
    std::function<void(FramePtr)> fc = ref(*tracking_call_ptr);

    std::promise<bool> initialized_promise;
    std::future<bool> initialized = initialized_promise.get_future();
    shared_ptr<VideoEngine> ve = nullptr;
    shared_ptr<VideoEngine*> ve_ptr = make_shared<VideoEngine*>(nullptr);
    shared_ptr<tbb_app> app = nullptr;
    Config* raw_conf = conf.get();
    std::function<DGStatus(DGFrame)> pushcall = bind([](DGFrame f, std::function<void(ObjPtrWithFramePtr)>&& _dc,
                std::function<void(FramePtr)>&& _fc,
                shared_ptr<VideoEngine*> _ve_ptr,
                std::promise<bool>&& _initialized_promise,
                ::Config* _raw_conf) -> DGStatus {
        if (*_ve_ptr == nullptr) {
            *_ve_ptr = VideoEngine::NewVideoEngineFromConfPtr(_raw_conf, f.w, f.h, _dc, _fc);
            _initialized_promise.set_value(true);
        }
        (*_ve_ptr)->PushFrame(f);
    }, std::placeholders::_1, std::move(dc), std::move(fc), ve_ptr, std::move(initialized_promise), raw_conf);
    std::shared_ptr<std::function<DGStatus(DGFrame)>> pushcall_ptr = make_shared<std::function<DGStatus(DGFrame)>>(std::move(pushcall));
```

compiling error is confusing. Why cann't I convert a bind result into a function?

```
/home/deepglint/code/dgstream/src/services/vse_service.cpp: In member function ‘Error VSEService::TaskNew(const dgvse::NewTaskRequest*, dgvse::NewTaskResponse*)’:
/home/deepglint/code/dgstream/src/services/vse_service.cpp:99:109: error: conversion from ‘std::_Bind_helper<false, VSEService::TaskNew(const dgvse::NewTaskRequest*, dgvse::NewTaskResponse*)::__lambda13, const std::_Placeholder<1>&, std::function<void(ObjPtrWithFramePtr)>, std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<ObjFrame>)>, std::shared_ptr<VideoEngine*>&, std::promise<bool>, Config*&>::type {aka std::_Bind<VSEService::TaskNew(const dgvse::NewTaskRequest*, dgvse::NewTaskResponse*)::__lambda13(std::_Placeholder<1>, std::function<void(ObjPtrWithFramePtr)>, std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<ObjFrame>)>, std::shared_ptr<VideoEngine*>, std::promise<bool>, Config*)>}’ to non-scalar type ‘std::function<DGStatus(DGFrame)>’ requested
     }, std::placeholders::_1, std::move(dc), std::move(fc), ve_ptr, std::move(initialized_promise), raw_conf);
                                                                                                             ^
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/dgstream.dir/services/vse_service.cpp.o] 错误 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/dgstream.dir/all] 错误 2
make: *** [all] 错误 2
```

Comment: It has a flaw at the beginning of the design, but I have very a little time to turn it into a workflow which would bind no local variable into a lambda passed to another thread.

Comment: Your lambda does not return any `DGStatus` despite of having `-> DGStatus` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't need to bind anything there.

You can try removing bind completely and specify how you want to capture your arguments inside capture clause [], e.g.
`[&dc, &fc, ve_ptr...]`, and adjust lambda arguments to match required signature.